# How long is the waiting time for having a phone/Skype interview?

Tags: faculty-application

I applied for some faculty positions, starting from Nov 01 to Nov 15 and one on Dec 01. I was wondering how long it takes for the search committee to shortlist the candidates for a phone/Skype interview?

Answer (score 1):

When does the call close? I'd think likely 6 weeks after that - you could reach and ask how long they anticipate the committee search to take. Usually the committee is made up of multiple faculty members so I would imagine it would be post - holidays.

Comment: I really don't want to bug them, especially at this moment. Because I am sure narrowing down the candidate to something like 10-15 candidates is really time-demanding. I was not sure about the processing time for selecting the semi-finalists when they have 200-300 candidates. Your answer makes sense as we have holidays ahead. They should start calling the candidate in Jan.

Comment: The call was closed on Dec. 15, 2018. Are you saying that the Skype interview will be after the holidays? Because, as I mentioned, I am not sure how long it takes for the search committee to make the semi-finalists (for Skype interview)

Comment: In my experience, no way to know for sure. I had answers anywhere from 3 weeks to 3 months afterward, from postdocs and TT processes, both positives and negatives. It's a bit like buying stuff from china, you do it hoping to be surprised down the road...